# How to call theme default widget in custom template?

Tags: widgets

I have default widget available called "Recent Post" created by theme. I want to call that widget in my custom template which I made.

I am trying in following way , But that is not working.

```
 <?php get_widget( 'WP_Widget_Recent Posts' ); ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Recent_Posts', array('number' => 10, 'title' => 'My Title Goes Here'), $args ); ?>
```

Comment: Excellent. It is working , Just want to know which arguments I need to pass If I want to call thumbnail and some content with read more link?

Comment: You may read more here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget Codex is your friend :)

Comment: Yep , Accepted..